# Django Celery Webshop: order confirmation email not sent

Tags: django, email, celery

I'm doing the webshop tutorial of the book "Django By Example". I'm using Windows.

I created the order form page. Looking nice. After sending the order, the website says:
"Thank you. Your order has been successfully completed. Your order number is 7".
But the "customer" does not receive the order confirmation email.

The other command prompt, that is running the celery, gives this kind of an error:

```
"ConnectionRefusedError: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it."
```

What you should have in the command prompt according to the book:

```
[2015-09-14 19:43:47,526: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: orders.
tasks.order_created[933e383c-095e-4cbd-b909-70c07e6a2ddf]
[2015-09-14 19:43:50,851: INFO/MainProcess] Task orders.tasks.
order_created[933e383c-095e-4cbd-b909-70c07e6a2ddf] succeeded in
3.318835098994896s: 1
```

If I add the code below to the settings.py then the order confirmation email is successfully sent to the command prompt.

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'
```

I don't know if this problem is connected to RabbitMQ. I don't know if it's working or not in my system now. Earlier I did do the Erlang and RabbitMQ installations as best as I could. 
[cmatskas.com](https://cmatskas.com/getting-started-with-rabbitmq-on-windows/): "RabbitMQ runs, by default, as a Windows Service and technically you shouldn’t need to do anything else to start interacting with it."

Edit: (I'm adding my tasks.py that I think could be helpful for getting the SMTP2GO working).
**orders/tasks.py**

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail import send_mail
from .models import Order


@task
def order_created(order_id):
    """
    Task to send e-mail notification when an order is successfully created.
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order.id)
    message = 'Dear {}, \n\nYou have successfully placed an order.\
                Your order id is {}.'.format(order.first_name, order.id)
    mail_sent = send_mail(subject, message, 'admin@myshop.com', [order.email])
    return mail_sent
```

Below is my unsuccessful attempt to add the smtp2go step 2 code to the tasks.py of the book tutorial. Would be great to know (or get some hints on) how to get it working:

```
from celery import task
from django.core.mail import EmailMultiAlternatives
from .models import Order


@task
def order_created(order_id):
    """
    Task to send e-mail notification when an order is successfully created.
    """
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    subject = 'Order nr. {}'.format(order.id)
    from_email = 'Max Burgers'
    to = order.email
    text_content = 'Dear {}, \n\nYou have successfully placed an order.\
                Your order id is {}.'.format(order.first_name, order.id)
    html_content = '<p>This is an awesum <strong>HTML</strong> message.</p>'
    msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(subject, text_content, from_email, [to])
    msg.attach_alternative(html_content, "text/html")
    msg.send()
    return
```

Answer (score 0):

If the `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting is not specified, Django tries to send email through (unsecured) SMTP server on local machine. Which in your case probably doesn't exists.

You have to configure the server through which you will be sending (real) emails. I recommend using [smtp2go](http://www.smtp2go.com/), which is really good service and free for small amount of emails (20/day).

They also have tutorial on Django setup: https://www.smtp2go.com/docs/django/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice @Domen . What I am confused about is just where in my application should I put the code in the Step 2 of the Django setup tutorial, that you mentioned?
Should I somehow merge the smtp2go step 2 tutorial code with my tasks.py? I added my current orders/tasks.py file into the question.
I tried to search advice for this problem elsewhere by I did not find, so I'd be really happy for another tip for how to go forwards.

Comment: Yes, this looks right. Try to execute the code in Django shell (`python manage.py shell`) to confirm that emails are send. And once that this works, move code to celery task.

Comment: Thanks again for your help. I tried to add the snippet of code at the website with the tasks.py of the book, but it didn't work and I'm quite lost with how exactly I should do it. I will add my attempt, the Frankenstein-code, to the question part now. Would be great to get some more help with this.